# Is twilio mandatory to access whatsapp api

Tags: node.js, twilio, whatsapp

My requirement is to send whatsapp message from the web page.  So, it should be a single page which will have fields To Mobile number, message and send button.

I found the documentation from facebook that we need to get whatsapp business api for this.
I also see some other tools like twilio to achieve this.
It is just confusing that, If we can achieve it using whatsapp business api itself, why we require twilio
So, My question here is, Is twilio or other third party tools really require to access whatsapp api.

Note: i am planning to do this implementation with node js.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the Facebook documentation deeper, you would see that direct access to WhatsApp business API is not fully available to the public. However, Facebook has partnered with 3rd party business solution providers to provide an interface for you to integrate with whatsapp. Here's a list of their partners [here](https://web.facebook.com/business/partner-directory/search?solution_type=messaging&platforms=whatsapp.).
In order for you to even stand a chance of directly accessing their APIs, you need to boast of a really high traffic and voluminous users attached to your product. So your best bet is via the 3rd party vendors.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Olamide226 is correct that you can directly access the API, but that it is easier through a partner like [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/api).

I will note that you may want to consider your exact use-case against WhatsApp's requirements for API use. Most importantly, you must get [explicit opt-in from users to receive WhatsApp messages from your business](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/overview/getting-opt-in).

Also, there are two types of message:

- Notifications: which you can send at any time, but must match a [registered template](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates#whatsapp-message-templates-overview) and fit within [the WhatsApp defined categories listed here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates#whatsapp-notification-categories)
- Conversations: if you have received a response from a user within the last 24 hours you can send messages in any format (they don't have to match a template)